# Mailchimp API 3.0 batch/bulk untag

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0, mailchimp-api-v3

I have a problem with untag the subscribers in a bulk with the Mailchimp API.

In the documentation https://mailchimp.com/developer/guides/how-to-use-tags/#Tag_multiple_contacts_in_bulk  is the example:

```
{
    "members_to_remove": [
        "john.smith@example.com",
        "brad.hudson@example.com"
        ]
}
```

Below can you see my PHP code where I with the $methode variable give the value **members_to_remove** and the $email value is an array with email addresses.

But the script does only add tags with a bulk to the subscriptions instead of remove.

What do I wrong?

```
public function tag_mailchimp($list_id, $email, $tag, $method) {

    $authToken = 'HERE MY KEY';
    // The data to send to the API


    $postData = array(
        $method => $email
    );

    // Setup cURL
    $ch = curl_init('https://us2.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/'.$list_id.'/segments/'.$tag);

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Authorization: apikey '.$authToken,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ),
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postData)
    ));

    // Send the request
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: This could be a typo in the doc - try to use DELETE instead of POST and see if that works.

Comment: Print out the post data json that you're sending.  I'm doing this in the Python api and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, but I don't know what I do else.., the code:

```
foreach($members as $member) {

   $list[] = $member->email;

}

$Mailer->tag_mailchimp('12345678', $list, 123456, 'members_to_remove');
```

And in the class I have the next function:

```
public function tag_mailchimp($list_id, $email, $tag, $method) {

        $authToken = 'HERE MY KEY';
        // The data to send to the API


        $postData = array(
            $method => $email
        );

        // Setup cURL
        $ch = curl_init('https://us2.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/'.$list_id.'/segments/'.$tag);

        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Authorization: apikey '.$authToken,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            ),
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postData)
        ));

        // Send the request
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        return $response;
    }
```